# JavaScript equivalent to Guava's Preconditions?

Tags: javascript, guava

In Java, I check my [preconditions](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) using Google Guava:

```
public Port getPublishedPort(Port port) {
    checkArgument(port.isPublishedPort(), "Given port %s is not a published port.", port);
```

Is there an equivalent to this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 10):

The Node.js [Preconditions Library](https://github.com/corybill/preconditions) is billed as having a Guava-like API for precondition checks.

> Support for Guava like Precondition error checking in Node.js

```javascript
new InstanceValidator(port).checkArgument(
        "publishedPort", "Given port %s is not a published port.", [port]);
```

Comment: What is the syntax for checking equality?

Comment: Crazy late response, but I just use .shouldBeTruthy

Comment: I haven't used this library, but I've added a usage example based on my understanding based on its documentation.

Answer (score 7):

I authored [Requirements.js](https://github.com/cowwoc/requirements.js). Usage looks like this:

```
import {requireThat} from "@cowwoc/requirements/es6/node/DefaultRequirements.js"

class Player
{
  constructor(name, age)
  {
    requireThat(name, "name").isNotNull().asString().length().isBetween(1, 30);
    requireThat(age, "age").asNumber().isBetween(18, 30);
  }
}
```

The primary focus is on the readability. Here is what the output looks like:

```
RangeError: age must be in range [18, 30).
Actual: 15
```

I welcome your feedback.

Comment: Looks great! It would be better without "asString" and "length" method. 

requireThat(name).as("name"//to name in errors (optional  - default: Object))
.isString()
.isNotNull()
.isLenghtBetween(1, 30)
.isRegex(etc)

Comment: Upvote for the completeness of this library, good job.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a version of Preconditions for JavaScript which is named [condicio](https://github.com/vivin/condicio). It's quite similar to Guava's Preconditions, but has some added functionality for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could write your own like:

```
var Preconditions = {
  checkArgument: function(condition, message) {
    if (!condition) {
      throw Error('IllegalArgumentException: ' + (message || ''));
    }
  }
}
```

and in your business logic

```
function getPublishedPort(port) {
  Preconditions.checkArgument(port.isPublishedPort(), 'Given port is not a published port.');
  // ... Business logic ...
}
```

Though I guess it can't do formatting with lazy evaluation for you.